# Regular expression to take on letter from imput

Tags: python, regex, text

I'm making a question and answer sheet and need a Regular expression which takes an input, and replaces it with the first letter of the input

For Example:

```
hello world
```

Becomes:

```
h w
```

And more, I am trying to change:

```
(hello world)
```

to:

```
(___)HW
```

This is to create memory cues for the answer sheet

Comment: Do you want a single pattern for both strings?

Comment: Hi UnbearableLightness,
I'm not sure what you mean by 'a single pattern' (sorry, I'm pretty new to this).  For every instance of text inside parentheses, I want to get the first letter of each word in the () and put them outside the ()

Comment: so 
    The (Frontal Lobe) is a part of the (brain)
Will become     
    The (__)FL is a part of the (__)B

Comment: oh cool! Thank you so much! 
I'm actually using atom and it didn't work for the find and replace feature in there. It did work in the regex tester though. Any advice on what I should do next. Should I leave the atom editor and work out how to do this in an actual programming language...or is there something else I need to consider to do this in atom?

Comment: Do you have a variable number of words in the parentheses? And are you working in Python?

Comment: All good, In atom I just needed to replace \ with $
so this worked!
$1___$4$2$3

Comment: That's one other thing, some times I have whole sentences inside the parentheses...

Comment: I have started trying to learning python, but when working with text I normally am just using the find and replace feature within atom. I guess this is showing me that if I'm getting more complicated with this I really need to start doing this in python

Comment: Yeah, in certain editors you may have to use `$` instead. Yes, the pattern below works for one to two words, as far as I am aware it's not possible to repeat the capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(\()([a-zA-Z])\S+ ?(?:([a-zA-Z])\S+)?(\))
```

- `(\()` First capturing group. Match and capture a `)`.
- `([a-zA-Z])` Match and capture letter.
- `\S+ ?` Any non whitespace characters, followed by optional whitespace.
- `(?:([a-zA-Z])\S+)?` Non capturing group. Match and capture letters, then match any non whitespace. The non capturing group is optional.
- `(\))` Match and capture a `)`.

Replacing with:

`\1___\4\U\2\3`.

You can try the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/yNkwkW/2).

---

For input strings:

```
(hello world)

The (Frontal Lobe) is a part of the (brain)
```

The output is:

```
(___)HW

The (___)FL is a part of the (___)B
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing :D

Comment: @QuantumDuckGoesQuark You are welcome, consider upvoting if you found the answer useful :)